# Excel: Find a key word in a transaction and bring the corresponding nature from a mapping list

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

Upon some extensive research, I couldn't find any answer to my problem. Here it is. Every month, I breakdown my transactions (from bank statements) according to their nature such as food, shopping and entertainment. So I prepared a key word mapping with natures as follows:

Column A - Column B

- Walmart - shopping
- Netlix - entertainment
- McDonalds - food

in two column in excel (list is pretty long, examples are simplified). Each transaction records includes many words and details of the transaction. What I want is, if a transaction includes the key word of **NETFLIX**, I need to bring word **ENTERTAINMENT** as nature next to the transaction column in excel. Example: if transaction is "*...June charge of **Netflix** obtained from credit card 12345...*" the key word **Netflix** is included in the transaction details, then bring **ENTERTAINMENT**. Had I kept my list short, I would have done it with =if(isnumber(search(... formula but my list is looong.

PS. Just extracting out the key word next to the transaction columnn would be fine, too. As the rest can be done by Vlookup.

I need your help friends.

The following formula didn't work for all transactions:

[image]

Comment: Any formula will use an array version as it will need to iterate the key words, if that list is long and there are many transaction, the only way to shorten it will be to use vba to do the whole list in mass.

Comment: I appreciate any help on this. I don't have any hands-on experience on VBA, but I can at least follow instructions if there is any resource. Please let me know. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a formula like this:

```
=INDEX(E:E,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($D$2:$D$4)/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($D$2:$D$4,A2))),1))
```

Realize that this is an array type formula and will iterate the entire key word list twice every time it is calced.  too many of these and the calc will be slow.

To ensure you are finding the full word:

```
=INDEX(E:E,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($D$2:$D$4)/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" "&$D$2:$D$4&" "," "&A2&" "))),1))
```

[image]

Comment: Something interesting going on here. My  list is quite long. I realized: when the related key words are relatively at the beginning of the list, the formula works correctly and brings the correct natures. However, when the related key words are way down in the list, the formula brings the wrong nature. I checked whether there is any key word in my transaction details, that brings the wrong nature. How can I fix this? Or a simpler question, it would be okay for me to bring the key word in the transaction. Back to my example, just bring the netflix, instead of entertainment. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please post the actual formula you are using.  Also remember that this will find the first match to the sub string, so if you have `Net` before `Netflix` it will return the match at `Net`.

Comment: Please see the edit in question post above. I added the screen shot below the question. I crosschecked whether it works properly. Formula doesn't work for some of the transactions. I don't understand why.

Comment: You will probably want to look into `Fuzzy Lookup` it is an addon.  your words must be full words.  you stop in the middle of a word in column B.  Also do not use full column inside the aggregate, it only exacerbates the number of iterations.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following setup:

[image]

With the following formula in `D1`:

```
=INDEX(B:B,MIN(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(" "&A1:A3&" "," "&C1&" ")),ROW(A1:A3),"")))
```

Note: This is array entered

Comment: Though I'm not sure if this is what you are after since you said: *"Had I kept my list short, I would have done it with =if(isnumber(search(... formula but my list is looong"*

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. However, it doesn't seem like working for my case. Please check the capture here (I couldn't post it here): https://www.facebook.com/photo?fbid=1627887044033564&set=a.1622289234593345 Can you help me where I am wrong?

Comment: Look like you not using keywords but keysentences rather.... @ibrahimtor

Comment: Yes because if keywords are short, it can be contained in many transactions which leads to wrong mapping. If keywords are long enough, chances are low for a keyword to appear in many transaction, which lead to a better mapping